# RegEx for JavaScript variables with nested names

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

When I needed to match a simple open-value JavaScript variable, I used the following RegEx:

```
\s*[a-zA-Z0-9$_]+\s*
```

Now I need to add support for nested properties, i.e. there can be dots (`.`) in the name, with the following considerations:

- `.` cannot be in the beginning or end
- a single `.` on its own is not valid
- repeated dots (`a..b`) are not allowed

What would be the right/simplest way to amend such a RegEx pattern?

If it makes any difference, I'm only interested in a version that will work under Node.js

---

**Valid Examples**

- `a`
- `a.b`
- `a.b.c`
- `_.$.123`

**Invalid Examples**

- ``
- `.`
- `.a`
- `a.`
- `a..b`

Comment: should bracket notation also be valid? i mean you could write a["b"] for example which is the same as a.b. Also variablenames cannot begin with a digit so I would look for a more perfect solution.

Comment: @Manticore Good question! In my case - no, I do not need brackets ;)

Comment: here is my approach: (?!\n)\s*[\w$]+(\.\w+)*(?=\s*\=.*?\;)

Comment: Could you please share a testing snippet? See [`^[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*(?:\.[\w$]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/0slZip/3), too.

Comment: here: https://regex101.com/r/uxRssP/2
but I guess I misunderstood your question, looking at your own regex fiddle

Comment: @Manticore Sorry, having problem with this test: `_.$.123` - I added in my valid examples, since this is what a valid JavaScript nested variable can be, also as per my original RegEx.

Comment: Note that your regex will also capture reserved keywords like `function` or `var`. I would recommend using an AST parser instead of a Regex if you want only variable names and nothing else. Otherwise the regex might become increasingly unwieldy.

Comment: @Peter I understand, but in my case it is perfectly fine, I only need a simple parser. I'm just looking for the minimum change on the existing RegEx ;)

Comment: If you want to extract substrings from larger text, since you cannot use a lookbehind, you will have to use something like [`(?:^|[^.])[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*(?:\.[\w$]+)*(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/0slZip/4) with a bit of code.

Comment: @Manticore Thank you for the suggestion, but in that demo it thinks that `value..house` is valid (should be not), and `_.$.123` should be valid (but it is not). Any chance you can change that to fix these? It then could make a good answer ;) Thank you again!

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/uxRssP/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay the simplest way I found is the following regex

```
^\s*(([a-zA-Z0-9$_][a-zA-Z0-9$_\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9$_])|([a-zA-Z0-9$_]))\s*$
```

It matches either a string of at least three characters with optional dots in the middle or a single character of the valid set. It works for the data in your example. If you want to match multiple variables in one line you could maybe use a negative look ahead like

```
\s*(?!\.)[a-zA-Z0-9$_\.]*(?!\.)\s*
```

The latter expression also works on your test data (http://regexr.com/3gra2) but will catch every whitespace between the variables so you might have to trim the result. I also fear that negative look aheads might become very complex on long texts.

As I mentioned in my comment the only reliable way of extracting variable names from JavaScript code is an abstract syntax treee (AST) parser that also considers keywords like `new`, `var`, `function` etc..

Comment: A little trouble with the `..` rule - should not allow repeated dots in the name ;)

Comment: I accepted the answer, even though the last requirement for `..` wasn't met. But I went for a much simpler and faster approach - to accept all dots, and check for validity later. So, basically I didn't need the answer in the end. But thank you anyway!

Comment: oh right, forgot about the double dots, sorry. I was wondering about why it has to be all-regex, so I'm glad you found a faster approach. Thanks for accepting.